# Vue.js Vuex - Delete in Database not reflected in view

Tags: vuex

I have a number of companies in the Vuex Store. Each company object has several objects within it ... to simplify for my question, imagine

> company{ id: 1, approval_notes: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}], fins:
>   {total_rev: 10000} }

I want to remove the approval_note with id of 2 from the company with the id of 1.

In the view, I have

```
deleteNote(obj) {
                if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this note?')) {
                    let path = '/api/approval_notes/' + obj.id;
                    axios.delete(path)
                        .then(function(rsp) {
                            this.$store.dispatch('delete_approval_note', obj);
                        }.bind(this))
                        .catch(function (err) {
                            console.log('AXIOS ERR', err);
                        }.bind(this));
                }
            }
```

The action is

```
export const delete_approval_note = ({commit}, payload) => {
    commit('DELETE_APPROVAL_NOTE', payload);
};
```

And the mutation is

```
export const DELETE_APPROVAL_NOTE = (state, payload) => {
    _.each(state.companies, function(co) {
        if(co.id = payload.company_id) {
            let notes = co.approval_notes;
            notes.splice(notes.indexOf(payload), 1);
        }
    });
};
```

The note is deleted from the database but the view does not update without a page refresh.

This type of thing I will be doing a bunch so it's important to me to understand this process since I obviously don't get it right now.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it actually remove it from notes?

Comment: not in "real-time" ... it does delete from the database and on page refresh, I am re-fetching the notes, so THEN it no longer shows. I need it to remove when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of IndexOf, using

```
notes.findIndex(obj => obj.id == payload.id)
```

It can get tricky when using IndexOf with complex object, I mostly rely on indexOf if dealing with simple values (integers, strings, booleans)